# Trouble writing Pulp constraint

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to solve a LP problem, I have a dataframe of 100 rows and 2 columns( let's say `a`, `b`) and I need to choose 10 rows such that following conditions should meet:

```
if a>=b then b/(a+b)>=0.2
if a<=b then a/(a+b)>=0.2
```

I tried following steps( Suppose dataframe is `df`)

1. Made a dummy variable c which contains only value 1 in each row and key representing each unique row.
2. Then `key=list(df['key'])`
3. `a=dict(zip(key,df['a']))`
4. `b=dict(zip(key,df['b']))`
5. `c=dict(zip(key,df['c']))`
6. `var=LpVariable.dicts('keys',key,lowBound=0,cat='Binary')`
7. `prob= *defined minimizing function*`
8. `prob+=lpSum([c[i]*var[i] for i in key)<=10`
9. `prob+=condition(lpSum([a[i]*var[i] for i in key),lpSum([b[i]*var[i] for i in key))=1`

```
def condition(a,b):
   if a>=b and b/(a+b)>=0.2: return 1
   if a<=b and a/(a+b)>=0.2: return 1
   return 0
```

I am having trouble with the last step. Is there any work around?

Note: I understand there can be some other methods or tools to solve this kind of problems, but I have a restriction to go with Pulp since this is just a part of a bigger problem, so any guidance with this will be helpful.

Comment: I recommend that you first start with the pulp documentation: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/main/index.html and then the pulp examples: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am working with PuLP from last month but I never came across this kind of issue where I need to use OR condition in constraint. Can you please let me know which problem will help me, not to sound lazy, but I need this urgently and I will definitely go through all the examples but don't have time right now.

Comment: Should the conditions you mention be met for every row?  And `a_i` and `b_i` for row `i` are constant, right?

Comment: Yes a_i and b_i are constant for row. the conditions should be met for sum of 10 rows. Anyway I figured out the way. Thanks for help